# User Input in Oracle Application Express online

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

On the Oracle Application express online, I want to be able to read input from the user.

I want to write a SQL statement to display all employees with first names starting with the letter that the user inputs. I thought we write

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE first_name LIKE '&letter%';
```

But this doesn't work. It displays "no data found".

I also tried doing this , but it is still wrong. This one gives an error message "ORA-00911: invalid character" after I enter any letter.

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE first_name LIKE :letter%;
```

I am just a beginner and when I searched , I didn't understand what my mistake is. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Saying that something "doesn't work" doesn't help us much.  Your question would be much better if you included things like the Oracle error message that you are getting or a description of the results you are seeing vs. the results that you are expecting.  We can guess what the problem might be but we might guess wrong.

Comment: I added the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `P1_LETTER` is the name of the text field page item that you have created for users to enter the letter, you'd want

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 WHERE first_name LIKE :p1_letter || '%'
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 WHERE substr(first_name,1,1) = :p1_letter
```

Remember that string comparisons are case sensitive.  So if a user types in "j", they won't match to "Justin".  They'll only match to "justin".  You may want to convert both sides of the expression to lower or upper-case in order to do a case-insensitive comparison.

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 WHERE lower(first_name) LIKE lower(:p1_letter) || '%'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and I understand now. Your examples are extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late but I've been encountering the same problem recently and i just found out that instead of using the `&` try `:` like the following, it should work nicely!

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE first_name LIKE ':letter%';
```